# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" while trying to get array of ids from selected rows in b-table

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, axios, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue tables selectable prop  i can get the selected rows but that contain all the properties of the rows but i want only the id of the selected  rows.
to do this tried this

```
 getids(){
for (var i = 0; i <= this.selected.length; i++) {
        this.filteredORD_NO.push(this.selected[i].id)
      } }
```

where selected [] is the selected array which contain all properties of the row and filteredORD_NO[] is an array which contain ids extracted from the selected [] array. this does work when i call the function directly eg by btn , but shows "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when i try to sed this data to the backend.
"

```
    assignmethod() {
      this.getids(),
        this.WorkToteam[0] = this.filteredORD_NO,
        this.WorkToteam[1] = this.selectedteam,
     
      console.log(WorkToteam);
      this.axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/path/to/backend",
        data: this.workToteam,
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("ikey") },
      })
        .then(
          (response) => (
            console.log("response"),
          
          )
        )
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
```

Comment: if there is another  way to get the ids of selected rows in b-table is also appreciated

Answer (score 0):

filteredORD_NO must be an array
declaring like filteredORD_NO: [], solved the issue.